# What is the Stack Overflow business model?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm not sure how Stack Exchange makes money from Stack Overflow. Could someone explain how they do that?

Comment: Cross site dupe: [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79435)

Comment: I've reopened this post; asking about the company is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I would have thought it belongs on MSE, no? As you yourself pointed out, there's already a question there about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: just because something is posted there doesn't mean there cannot be a question about it here. Yes, there is some overlap here, that's not necessarily a problem, as most visitors to SO will come here, not go to MSE.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I hate this split :(

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Quoting Jeff Atwood (Stack Overflow founder), over on [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model)

> Three ways:
>
> 1. Job listings (e.g. the traditional classified ad model)   http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-listings
> 2. CV Search (e.g. the new-fangled and IMO vastly superior dating model)   http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-search
> 3. Traditional, but respectful (e.g. no animation or flash or pop-anything) display advertising on SO, SF, and to a lesser extent
>    SU. https://stackexchange.com/about/contact

E.g. Stack Overflow attracts developers, who then also discover Careers. Careers collects their CVs (by making you happy about not being contacted by recruiters all the time and because you can show off your Stack Overflow profile there), then sells access to those CVs to companies looking for developers. Those companies also can pro-actively place jobs on Careers and advertise those jobs on Stack Overflow, where all the great developers hang out. Oh, and they do a few general non-flashy, non-trashy traditional ads for the developers too.

You may want to read the Stack Exchange blog; they [posted an interesting overview of how the Stack Exchange business model evolved](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/) when the company received $40 million from investors.

Comment: There are now [more sites](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit) accepting advertising: Android Enthusiasts, Arqade, Ask Different, Ask Ubuntu, Database Administrator, Drupal, Game Development, Programmers, Information Security, SharePoint, Unix/Linux, Web Applications, WordPress. On some of them banner ads already [appear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243364/) regularly. Also, "to a lesser extent SU" may be outdated; I don't see anything "lesser" about ads on SU.

Comment: One must also consider that you don't see most of the traditional ads if you are a contributer so the site (have over [200 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)).

Comment: @Raidri: I merely quoted an old post; the exact list of sites with ads hardly matters there, does it? What has my reputation got to do with this? I am well aware that lower rep users get more banner ads, I [wrote answers about those](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A100297+ads) before. :-)

Comment: @Yes: The "lesser" probably means they make less money from SU than from SO and SF.

Comment: And promo Tags like [tag:android]

Comment: @jasilva: sponsoring tags is an extension of the advertisement model.