# How does Stack Overflow make money?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering since I read [this](http://techcrunch.com/2015/01/20/stack-exchange-raises-40m-led-by-a16z-to-boost-its-programmer-forums/) just now.

So how does Stack Overflow produce a return for investors?

Comment: You know those ads you see? About those...

Comment: Check out [this MSO question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293840/what-is-the-stack-overflow-business-model) This question was asked there, so that should sum it up for you.

Comment: I actually haven't noticed any ads on the site. I just see links to other StackExchange sites, etc. I've noticed the "Bounty" reward for some questions and I was wondering if that brought them any income.

Comment: The tears of frustrated programmers are worth a fortune on the Chinese market.

Comment: @BuzzLightyear just go to an anonymous tab and visit Stack Overflow. You'll see the adds most visitors are seeing.

Comment: Bounties are made up of the reputation of the one who placed it, so no money there. I could see how you'd think that, though. Do you by chance have an ad blocker running? (Perhaps one you forgot you had running?) If so, that's why you aren't seeing the ads here. As a user under 200 rep, there are "banner ads" on questions you should see, and everyone should be seeing the ads in the sidebar.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for that and the joke! I see them now!

Comment: Doesn't it say in the article? `Spolsky says that two-thirds of its revenues today come from recruitment services, via its Stack Overflow Careers site, and one-third from advertising.`

Comment: @BuzzLightyear to infinity and beyond... that's the business model of Stack Exchange :-)

Comment: Bart doesn't do jokes...